# Unable to build wxMSW-2.8.12 using MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets, mingw32

I have tried two different versions of gcc (4.6 and 4.7) with several configurations including

```
make -f makefile.gcc USE_OPENGL=1 BUILD=debug SHARED=0 RUNTIME_LIBS=static UNICODE=1
make -f makefile.gcc MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=debug SHARED=0 UNICODE=1
make -f makefile.gcc USE_OPENGL=1 BUILD=debug UNICODE=1
```

This is the error

```
../../src/msw/thread.cpp:525: error: cast from 'void*' to 'THREAD_RETVAL' loses precision
../../src/msw/thread.cpp: In member function 'wxThreadError wxThreadInternal::WaitForTerminate(wxCriticalSection&, void**, wxThread*)':
../../src/msw/thread.cpp:845: error: cast from 'void*' to 'DWORD' loses precision
../../src/msw/thread.cpp: In member function 'void wxThread::Exit(void*)':
../../src/msw/thread.cpp:1165: error: cast from 'void*' to 'unsigned int' loses precision
```

My platform is Windows 7 64-bit but am not trying to build a 64-bit library ( not intentionally anyway)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and the question is ...?

Comment: @hochl The question is what is it that I am not doing right, i.e. what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens when trying to build wxWidgets using MinGW-w64. In my case the source of my troubles was that I had Strawberry Perl 5.14.2.1 (64bit) installed and wasn't aware that
perl had installed a gcc compiler which was in the path.

Answer (score 2):

DWORD is a 32 bit value while on 64 bit architecture a pointer is a 64 bit value. The code should be using DWORD_PTR which gets defined to a 64 bit value on x86_64 and 32 bits on x86.
Possibly you should just build this as a 32 bit application and avoid trying to build it as a native 64 bit app.

Comment: I am certainly trying to build a 32-bit library but your observation seems to agree somewhat with other reports I have seen while researching this error. Users run into this when trying to use MinGW-w64 but my version is clearly 32-bit